# Installing New Relic .NET Agent in an Azure Web Role

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles, newrelic

I configured the Free Standard Version of New Relic in my Azure portal in the ADD-ONS section. I created a new Web Role and I'm deploying my ASP.NET application successfully to this web role. I added the NewRelicWindowsAzure package from NuGet. I re-deployed my web application and I'm getting nothing registering in the New Relic control panel.

I believe the issue is not having the agent installed on the machines when it does a new full installation. When I RDP to the instance and install the agent it seems to work fine.

How can I shoehorn the installation into the deployment? I see the NuGet package added a newrelic.cmd in the root of my web app, so I tried to add that to the Azure Cloud Service project in the ServiceDefinition.csdef file like so:

`<Startup>
   <Task commandLine="newrelic.cmd" executionContext="elevated" />
</Startup>`

It seems to be installing -something-, but it looks like the New Relic Server Agent is installed but not started, and I don't see anything about the base APM Agent. How can I automate this installation successfully?

Answer (score 2):

Here was the answer. I had to apply more settings to this task:

`<Task commandLine="newrelic.cmd" executionContext="elevated" taskType="simple">
   <Environment>
      <Variable name="EMULATED">
         <RoleInstanceValue xpath="/RoleEnvironment/Deployment/@emulated" />
      </Variable>
      <Variable name="IsWorkerRole" value="false" />
      <Variable name="LICENSE_KEY">
         <RoleInstanceValue          xpath="/RoleEnvironment/CurrentInstance/ConfigurationSettings/ConfigurationSetting[@name='NewRelic.LicenseKey']/@value" />
      </Variable>
   </Environment>
</Task>`